# Why do I get a "Get-WindowSize" not implemented error when using the PowerShell call Get-Service on a remote machine?

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I have a Windows 10 host machine that connects to a Hyper-V Windows 10 VM hosted on the same box.
I've been following along the Pluralsight PowerShell tutorial.
I'm trying to get the services available on a remote computer.

I can start a session on the remote computer with the following command:

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName Client1 -Credential username
```

Once the session has started and I am connected, I attempt to call Get-Service to identify the services on the client computer.

```
[Client1]: PS C:\Users\username\Documents>Get-Service
```

When I run the above command, I get the following error message:

```
Remote host method get_WindowSize is not implemented.
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [out-lineoutput], PSRemotingDataStructureException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Management.Automation.Remoting.PSRemotingDataStructureException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutLineOutputCommand
```

I am running the same version of PowerShell on the host and client machines (**5.1.18362.145**).
I assume that somehow this is an issue on the client machine?

Comment: This is only an issue when I am running from PowerShell ISE.

Comment: This might be a [broken update](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/67142783-2acd-4d54-aef2-8d89d71457c5/powershell-remoting-broken-in-windows-10-1903?forum=winserverTS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Client1]: PS C:\Users\username\Documents>Get-Service | out-string

That should work, maybe a bug with PowerShell or new version of Windows 10

Other link : https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/67142783-2acd-4d54-aef2-8d89d71457c5/powershell-remoting-broken-in-windows-10-1903?forum=winserverTS

Answer (score 2):

```
"Remote host method get_WindowSize is not implemented."
```

This happens to all Remoting Sessions **started With Powershell_ISE** on the Client-Side.
The workaround with Out-String sucks, it destroys the Result-Object of that call.
Best fix so far is either using not ISE or embed your remote Procedure in a Script and call it with Powershell.exe

Really annoying...and not fixed by now.

**Workaround Example:** Instead of using `enter-pssession` and then asking for a result of running services, you could use: `$YourServices=Invoke-command -ComputerName <computername> -ScriptBlock {get-service}`. Then you have all Service-Stats in your Object `$YourServices`.

Comment: Would be helpful to post the workaround you mention if possible. Your answer is not particularly helpful for those looking at a solution.

Comment: Example: Instead using enter-pssession and then asking for a result of running services, you could use: 
$YourServices=Invoke-command -ComputerName <computername> -ScriptBlock {get-service}
Then you have all Service-Stats in your Object $YourServices